# How can I make lazy registration in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to make lazy registration in Flutter. I want the user to have access on home page and on some pages even he/she isn't logged in. I tried this tutorial: https://www.kodeco.com/28987851-flutter-navigator-2-0-using-go_router#toc-anchor-009 but here login/registration is guard page and don't have access to other pages. I just want that if the user is logged in, in bottom navigation bar return profile page, if not, return login page but other pages to be accessible in both case.

I tried this:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:photo_app/bottom_navigation_pages/basket_page.dart';
import 'package:photo_app/bottom_navigation_pages/drafts_page.dart';
import 'package:photo_app/bottom_navigation_pages/favorites_page.dart';
import 'package:photo_app/bottom_navigation_pages/login_page.dart';
import 'package:photo_app/bottom_navigation_pages/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:photo_app/ui/home_body.dart';

import '../login_state/login_state.dart';

//enum appPages { home, favorites, drafts, basket, profile }

class BottomNavigationBarPages extends ChangeNotifier {
late LoginState loginState;
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  int get selectedTab => _selectedTab;
  static var pages = [
    const HomeBody(),
    const FavoritesPage(),
    const DraftsPage(),
    const BasketPage(),
    loginState.loggedIn ? const ProfilePage() : const LoginPage(),
  ];

  void goToTab(index) {
    _selectedTab = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

but there is error:

```
The instance member 'loginState' can't be accessed in an initializer. (Documentation)  Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
```

Here is my routes:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:photo_app/bottom_navigation_pages/registration_pages/email_sign_up.dart';
import 'package:photo_app/login_state/login_state.dart';
import 'package:photo_app/ui/home.dart';

import '../bottom_navigation_pages/bottom_navigation_class_pages.dart';
import '../bottom_navigation_pages/profile_page.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import '../ui/error_screen.dart';
import '../ui/magnets_list.dart';

class MyRouter {
  final LoginState loginState;

  MyRouter(this.loginState);

  //AppStateManager appStateManager = AppStateManager();
  int selectedTab = BottomNavigationBarPages().selectedTab;
  late final router = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: loginState,
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: rootRouteName,
        path: '/',
        redirect: (state) =>
            state.namedLocation(homeRouteName, params: {'screen': 'homeBody'}),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: homeRouteName,
        path: '/:screen(homeBody|favorites|drafts|basket|profile)',
        //  name: 'bottomNavBar',
        builder: (context, state) {
          final String screen = state.params['screen']!;
          return Home(screen: screen);
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            name: subMagnetsListRouteName,
            path: 'magnets',
            builder: (context, state) => const MagnetList(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: subSignUpPage,
            path: 'sign-up',
            builder: (context, state) => const SignUpPage(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/homeBody',
        redirect: (state) =>
            state.namedLocation(homeRouteName, params: {'screen': 'homeBody'}),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/favorites',
        redirect: (state) =>
            state.namedLocation(homeRouteName, params: {'screen': 'favorites'}),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/drafts',
        redirect: (state) =>
            state.namedLocation(homeRouteName, params: {'screen': 'drafts'}),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/basket',
        redirect: (state) =>
            state.namedLocation(homeRouteName, params: {'screen': 'basket'}),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/profile',
        redirect: (state) =>
            state.namedLocation(homeRouteName, params: {'screen': 'profile'}),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: magnetsListRouteName,
        path: '/magnets',
        redirect: (state) => state.namedLocation(subMagnetsListRouteName,
            params: {'screen': 'homeBody'}),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: signUpPage,
        path: '/sign-up',
        redirect: (state) =>
            state.namedLocation(subSignUpPage, params: {'screen': 'profile'}),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: profilePage,
        path: '/profile-page',
        redirect: (state) =>
            state.namedLocation(profilePage, params: {'screen': 'profile'}),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: loginPage,
        path: '/login-page',
        redirect: (state) =>
            state.namedLocation(loginPage, params: {'screen': 'profile'}),
      ),
    ],
    errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorScreen(state.error),
/*    redirect: (state) {
      final login = state.namedLocation(loginPage);
      final profile = state.namedLocation(profilePage);
      final loggedIn = loginState.loggedIn;
      if (!loggedIn) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print(loggedIn);
        }
        return login;
      } else {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print(loggedIn);
        }
        return null;
      }
    },*/
  );
}
```

And here is my login state:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../constants.dart';

class LoginState extends ChangeNotifier {
  final SharedPreferences prefs;
  bool _loggedIn = false;

  LoginState(this.prefs) {
    loggedIn = prefs.getBool(loggedInKey) ?? false;
  }

  bool get loggedIn => _loggedIn;

  set loggedIn(bool value) {
    _loggedIn = value;
    prefs.setBool(loggedInKey, value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void checkLoggedIn() {
loggedIn = prefs.getBool(loggedInKey) ?? false;
  }
}
```

So how can I do it?
Thanks in advance